# No CKAN_SQLALCHEMY_URL specified when installing CKAN on Docker

Tags: docker, ckan

I'm following the instructions to install CKAN using Docker from http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.5.7/maintaining/installing/install-using-docker.html

However, after running ckan/ckan it will start for a second and stop immediately. After checking the container log I can see following error:

```
Distribution already installed:
ckan 2.8.0a0 from /usr/lib/ckan/venv/src/ckan
Creating /etc/ckan/ckan.ini
Now you should edit the config files
/etc/ckan/ckan.ini
ERROR: no CKAN_SQLALCHEMY_URL specified in docker-compose.yml
```

I have tried googling this and noticed people are having issues with installing CKAN using Docker but not this exact error.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into the same error. My solution was to use a previous commit as it seems the support for docker in the current / recent version it's broken. Ensure you remove all the docker containers and images first, then in the CKAN directory, checkout a working commit:

```html
git checkout 7506353
```

...ensure all the reminant docker components are gone:

```html
docker container prune
docker image prune
docker network prune
docker volume prune
```

And before you run the docker-compose build command, from your CKAN installation, open the following file:

ckan/migration/versions/000_add_existing_tables.py

..on line 8 (https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/master/ckan/migration/versions/001_add_existing_tables.py) add schema='public' as shown below:

```html
meta = MetaData(schema='public')
```